# Use Cordova plugin to send and receive SMS with Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I found this [cordova plugin](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/blob/master/test/index.html) that can send and receive SMS. I was wondering if anybody here has used this with Ionic? Or can somebody point me in the direction on how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize in advance for not giving a typed answer but only sharing a link, but the link has all you need to get started
[Ionic SMS Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms/)